# Is this a correct way of saving associations in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I'm trying to save to two association tables (tours/stops, and stops/venues) while saving one model (stops).  Tours has_many stops and stops belongs to both the association tables.. but because I'm in the Stops controller I can only seem to save via @tour.stops.create so I manually did a create..

**Here's my code from the stops controller**

```
class StopsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    tour_id = params[:stop][:tour_id]
    #check to make sure venue matches before saving
    venue_name = params[:stop][:venue_name]
    venue_id = Venue.find_by(name: venue_name).id



    @tour = Tour.find(tour_id)

    @stop = @tour.stops.create(strong_params)

    #this seems like it might be ghetto

    Stopsvenuesmembership.create!(venue_id: venue_id, stop_id: @stop.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the traditional way of doing this would be

```
@stop = @tour.stops.create(params)

@venue = Venue.find_by_name(venue_name) # or however you want to find it
@venue.stops << @stop
```

Comment: When I added this I got "undefined method `stops' for 7:Fixnum"

Comment: @user3155441 That's odd - I can't imagine that `.find_by_name` is ever going to return a number. Is it possible that you've somehow gotten `@venue` set to an id number rather than an object?